# from which table to take base quantity for production orders?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Does anybody know from which table to take base quantity for production orders? I think is in AFVV-MGVRG but I am not sure.

I need it in the structure below:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF tables_fields,


  AUFNR TYPE AUFK-AUFNR, "Nr comanda productie
*   AUFNR TYPE AUFM-AUFNR, "Nr comanda productie
*  MAKTX TYPE MAKT-MAKTX, "Descriere material
  AUART TYPE AUFK-AUART, "Tip comanda /Sectie
  WERKS TYPE AUFK-WERKS, "Unitate logistica
  TXT   TYPE T003P-TXT,  "Nume sectie
  "MENGE TYPE AUFM-MENGE, "Cantitate buc predata
  GAMNG TYPE AFKO-GAMNG, "Cantitatea totala vrac
  GMEIN TYPE AFKO-GMEIN, "Unitatea de masura kg cantitate totala
  "WEMNG TYPE AFPO-WEMNG, "Cantitatea totala livrata
  ERFMG TYPE AUFM-ERFMG, "Cantitatea totala livrata defalcata
  GSTRP Type AFKO-GSTRP, "Data lansarii comenzii
  GLTRP TYPE AFKO-GLTRP, "Data estimativa a finalizarii comenzii
  BLDAT TYPE AUFM-BLDAT, "Data finalizarii comenzii
  MGVRG TYPE AFVV-MGVRG, "Bucati pe comanda-cant de baza
  "MEINS TYPE AUFM-MEINS,"Unitate bucati pe comanda-rectificat
  MEINH TYPE AFVV-MEINH,  "Unitate de masura bucati pe comanda
  MENGE TYPE AUFM-MENGE, "Cantitate buc predata
*  BMENG TYPE STKO-BMENG, "Cantitatea de baza estimata
*  BMEIN TYPE STKO-BMEIN, "Unitatea de masura cantitatea de baza estimata
  MATNR TYPE AUFM-MATNR, "Cod material
  "PLNBEZ TYPE AFKO-PLNBEZ,"Cod material
  MAKTX TYPE MAKT-MAKTX, "Descriere material
   MBLNR TYPE AUFM-MBLNR,
  ZEILE TYPE AUFM-ZEILE,
  BMSCH TYPE AFVV-BMSCH,
  SPRAS TYPE T003P-SPRAS,"Restrictionare limba
  ZILEDEP TYPE I,"AFKO-GLTRP, "Filtru date intre care s-au realizat comenzi
  COMDEP(10) TYPE C,"Nr zile comanda depasita
  COMINTRE TYPE AFKO-GSTRP,"Data comenzi termen depasit
* ERDAT TYPE AUFK-ERDAT, "Data lansarii comenzii - campul vechi
* LTRMI TYPE AFPO-LTRMI, "Data finalizarii comenzii noul camp
 "ISTAT TYPE TJ02T-ISTAT,
  "TXT04 type TJ02T-TXT04, "Text scurt stare comanda
  "TXT30 TYPE TJ02T-TXT30, "Text lung stare comanda
  line_color(4) TYPE c,

   END OF tables_fields.
```

Comment: Tell us your full business requirement.

Comment: @Suncatcher, thank you for your reply. The requierement is that i need to bring the base quantity from a production process into my report along with :plant(AUFK-WERKS), type of command (AUFK-AUART),section name (T003P-TXT),material(AUFM-MATNR),required base quantity(AFVV-MGVRG),unit measure(AFVV-MEINH),quantity produced(AUFM-MENGE),required quantity in KG(AFKO-GMEIN),quantity in KG produced(AUFM-ERFMG),date launch order(AFKO-GSTRP),estimated date finish order(AFKO-GLTRP),date effectively finish order(AUFM-BLDAT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to convert a quantity in its base **unit**.

```
if lf_afpo_umren > 0.  "if 0 division by zero dump
  try. 
    lf_afpo_psmng_basme = lf_afpo_psmng * lf_afpo_umrez / lf_afpo_umren
  catch cx_sy_arithmetic_overflow.
    "do somethin, e.g. call function 'maximal_value_get'
  catch cx_sy_arithmetic_error.
    "do something, e.g. clear lf_afpo_psmng_basme.
else.
  "try it manually with table MARA/MARM
  "or try function module
  CALL FUNCTION 'MD_CONVERT_MATERIAL_UNIT'
    EXPORTING
      i_matnr              = lf_matnr
      i_in_me              = lf_afpo_amein
      i_out_me             = lf_mara_meins
      i_menge              = lf_afpo_psmng
    IMPORTING
      e_menge              = lf_afpo_psmng_basme
    EXCEPTIONS
      error_in_application = 1
      error                = 2
      OTHERS               = 3. 
    if sy-subrc <> 0.
     "do something, clear lf_quantity_basme   
endif.
```

Comment: thank you , you are right , in the mean time i already found the solution.

Answer (score -1):

it seems that the base quantity is calculated by AFPO-PSMNG / AFPO-UMREN. in this case the result is same as base quantity.